# skip or bypass 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' if one of the links goes down

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**i want to pass one of the links which is error, how to? i want to skip **

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('url.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

for x in data:
    y = x[1]
    url = "url"+y
#     print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
#     print(soup)
    league_table = soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-sm-4')`enter code here`
    **for team in league_table.find_all('ul', class_ = 'list-group'):**
        print(team)
```

Comment: You need to look up how to check whether a particular value is None -- most likely with `if value is None`.  How are you stuck on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check to see if the `requests.get` call was successful and continue on to the next URL if it was not, then a code snippet like this should do the trick:

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```